# PL/SQL (mod_plsql): Accept parameters only from POST, not GET requests?

Tags: post, parameters, plsql, mod-plsql

I'm working on an application that uses mod_plsql with Oracle 10G to generate web pages via PL/SQL stored procedures called directly from the web browser. I'm looking for a way to only accept parameters via POST requests, and not GET requests.

Ie, in PHP I would only want the value of $_POST['parameter_name'] and not $_GET['parameter_name']. I haven't been able to find a way to achieve this in Pl/SQL, since the parameters are specified in the procedure definition and without a request type.

Is there any way to achieve this with PL/SQL?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have access to the Apache config, you can probably put the following code at the top of your Oracle procedure:

```
if owa_util.get_cgi_env('REQUEST_METHOD') != 'POST' then
    raise_application_error(-20001,'Only POST request method is allowed.');
end if;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Apache configuration, you can probably use the [Limit directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limit) to restrict the relevant URLs to POST requests.